# Introducing a line break into a file having different columns on the basis of text in the value column

Tags: awk, sed, cat, columns, csh

I would like to introduce a line break into a file having different columns on the basis of the value in the first column.

For example:

Input file:

```
1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800
1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466
1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87
1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```

Required output:

```
1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800

1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466

1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87

1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```

I tried the csh script, but it didn't worked.

```
#! /bin/csh
set bin = /home/x/bin

foreach i (`cat pdb_ligands | awk '{print $1}'`)
        echo $i
        sed "s/$i/&\n\n/" pdb_ligands > output.txt
end
```

Comment: if the first field has a fixed number of characters, as in your example data, this works: `uniq -w 4 --group < infile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 && $1 != prev { print "" } { prev = $1 }; 1' pdb_ligands
1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800

1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466

1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87

1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```

This keeps track of what was in the 1st column on the previous line in `prev`.

If the current 1st column is different from `prev`, and we are not on the first line of the file, a newline is printed.  All lines are then printed unconditionally.

---

An alternative to `print ""` in the code above is to do `$0 = ORS $0`, which adds a newline character (or whatever `ORS`, the output record separator, is set to) to the start of the current record.

This will have the effect of producing an extra newline when the line is printed moments later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tagging this pbm under the csh, so here's a cshell-ian way to go about it. The foreach loop reads the file pdb_ligands on a per-line basis and then splits the line into fields. We unconditionally print every line but emit an empty line which satisfies the condition shown.

```
  #!/bin/csh -f
  set prev = ""
  @ line_num = 1
  foreach line ( "`cat pdb_ligands`" )
    set fields = ( ${line:x} )
    set curr = "${fields[1]}" 
    if ( "$line_num" > 1 && "$prev" != "$curr" ) echo
    printf '%s\n' "$line" 
    set prev = "$curr"
    @ line_num++
  end
```

Method-GNU sed. Maintain a pattern space of two consecutive lines so that we can monitor any change in the first column between the two consecutive rows. Only if there's a change in the first fields us detected we emit an empty line by means of printing the empty hold space.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    $q;N;P
    /^(\S+)\s.*\n\1\s/!{x;p;x;}
    D
' pdb_ligands
```

Using awk we read the next line and find the index of the current line's first field in the next line. Should it occur at the beginning means it's a match. So we set ORS to RS. Otherwise, an empty line setting is used.

```
$ awk '{ while ( getline t > 0 ) {
      ORS = index(t, $1 FS)-1 ? RS RS : RS
      print; $0 = t }
}1' pdb_ligands
```

The perl follows the same technique as the awk one.

```
$ perl -pae '
    print; $_ = <>;
    /^\Q$F[0]\E\s/ or print $/;
    redo if ! eof;
' pdb_ligands 

1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800

1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466

1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87

1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in `awk '{if(!seen[$1]++){print $1}}'  filename `; do sed -n '/'$i'/p'  filename ;echo -e "\n"; done



output

1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800


1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466


1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87


1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```

python

```
import re
uniqueele=[]
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    q=i.split(' ')[0]
    if q not in uniqueele:
        uniqueele.append(q)


for g in uniqueele:
    o=re.compile(r'{0}'.format(g))
    t=open('filename','r')
    for h in t:

        if re.search(o,h):
            print h.strip()

    print "\n"
```

output

```
1aa6 HETATM 4MO A 803
1aa6 HETATM SF4 A 800


1ao0 HETATM 5GP A 467
1ao0 HETATM SF4 B 466
1ao0 HETATM SF4 C 466


1b0y HETATM SF4 A  87


1blu HETATM SF4 A 101
1blu HETATM SF4 A 102
```